xargs not recognzing the --verbose option inside docker command script
I am using the solution @Krzysztof proposes in Restarting an unhealthy docker container based on healthcheck.   I have made one change to the original, adding --verbose so that the command docker restart <ID> will go to the docker log driver.
While --verbose works fine from the CLI on my host,   the same argument is rejected when it is run by the unhealthy_container_restarter container.
For example,  docker container:
    unhealthy_container_restarter:
        image: docker:cli
        network_mode: none
        cap_drop:
           - ALL
        volumes: [ "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock" ]
        command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "while true; do sleep 60; docker ps -q -f health=unhealthy | xargs --verbose --no-run-if-empty docker restart; done" ]
        restart: unless-stopped

results in this error output when there is another unhealthy container for it to restart:
{"line":"xargs: unrecognized option: verbose","source":"stderr",.......}

This command with the same syntax works interactively:
$ sudo docker ps -q -f name=xxxx$ | xargs --verbose --no-run-if-empty sudo docker restart;

sudo docker restart ab14c1cxxxx9
ab14c1cxxxx9


Is there something special about --verbose in this context?   The --no-run-if-empty argument is working fine.

--verbose isn't a defined option in POSIX-standard xargs(1).  If your runtime environment is something like an Alpine container or something else based on BusyBox or BSD tooling, it might not recognize this option.
The GNU findutils documentation notes that long-form --verbose is the same as short-form -t, which is a standard option.  Similarly, --no-run-if-empty has short form -r, which is in (current) POSIX xargs(1).
This is more likely to work if you use the short options, like
docker ps -q -f health=unhealthy | xargs -t -r docker restart

BusyBox xargs(1) (which would be used in an Alpine container) also supports both options.  The 2018 version of POSIX.1 did not include -r but the 2024 edition does.

This is helpful.    I simply checked the xargs in my Linux distro.  I didn't think to compare that to the POSIX standard.    I've updated the docker compose and will wait for the container to become unhealthy
